# Apply a function to every sub-matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to make the following code faster:

```
A = DxNxNxN matrix
for i=1:D
   A(i,:,:,:) = ifftn(A(i,:,:,:));
end
```

I have been looking into the arrayfun function. I guess this should be possible with a conversion to cell, but I'd rather avoid that to increase performance (couldn't make it work either).

Comment: The performance might not increase so much by eliminating for-loops. see the following link: http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the `ifft` along the three dimensions:

```
A = ifft(ifft(ifft(A,[],2),[],3),[],4);
```

Whether this is faster or not probably depends on `D` and `N`.

Another possibility is

```
A = fft(ifftn(A),[],1);
```

although this is probably wasteful, as the first dimension gets transformed back and then forth.

Comment: Thanks, but this is actually slower than a for loop for some reason (N=128, D~1:100).